# How to identify multiple lines/clusters in a single dataset

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I'm currently struggling to wrap my head around how multi-linear regression could be done to find separate sets of linear models in a single data set. I can perform regression on single data set for a single regressor and coef with no problem, but what if there are a known-number of lines existing in a single data space?

My first approach was to use hierarchical clustering to identify the points using ML first, but it doesn't seem to capture individual 
cluster variance in Euclidean space as expected. My second trial was KMeans, which still relies on Euclidean distance so it creates clusters with radii. My last thought process led to Kmedian, but at this point I was wondering what other people might think regarding this problem.
If this is the right direction, I know I would have to project points in a better space(i.e. an axis that captures more-or most- variance) before I apply these methods.

I would appreciate any comments or input in any shape or form.

Thank you,

3-line summary:
Linear regression on dataset with multiple lines
Clustering first, then multiple single linear regression?
or have you guys come across a module for this such thing?

I would truly appreciate any insights;

Comment: Theory questions like this are more on-topic for the [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack sites. You may get better answers there.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You can implement your own version of k-means. Instead of grouping by distance to cluster center, group by distance to a certain line. You might assign random clusters to each point initially. Then, find the best-fit line for each cluster. Go through all of your points and assign each point to the cluster of the line it's closest to. Then find the best-fit again and repeat.

Comment: @meesinlid did you find a solution for this problem? I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283688/scatter-plot-regression-in-python-when-having-different-groups-of-data) that might be related to this